# NestJS pipe Joi.validate() (is not a function)

Tags: hapi.js, nestjs

I try to use Joi validator on **NestJS** with pipe.

https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#object-schema-validation

```js
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    private readonly schema: Joi.ObjectSchema,
  ) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { error } = Joi.validate(value, this.schema);

    if (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

It doesn't work properly.

> TypeError: Joi.validate is not a function

Comment: Can you try with `Joi.object(this.schema).validate(value)` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `schema.validate` in place of `Joi.validate`, for example:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
});
const result = schema.validate(req.body);
```

or for more info go to https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.8

Answer (score 1):

I have made an PR to update the https://docs.nestjs.com and it looks like it is already deployed, so you can refer to it.

`@hapijs/joi` deprecated `Joi.validate` with version 16 and you have to call `.validate` directly on schema.